# PHP preg_match not giving result

Tags: php, regex

I am having some problems trying to datamine this site, maybe you can help?

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://store.steampowered.com/app/8190/');

$regexp='#<a href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=2" class="name">(.*?)</a>#';
preg_match($regexp,$content,$string1);

print_r($string1);
```

This code doesn't seem to work, maybe it seems obvious to you? Thanks :)

Comment: Can't even get the content from: `http://store.steampowered.com/app/8190/`

Comment: I can 
    echo $content
and all html is pasted on my website.

Comment: Just escape the dot and the question mark because they have special meaning in a regex. Here is a tuto: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

You have not escaped the hyperlink tag, try this:

```
$regexp='#<a\s+href\s+=\s+"http://store\.steampowered\.com/search/\?category2=2"\s+class\s+=\s+"name">(.*?)</a>#';
```

You need to escape parts of the string that you do not want parsed as special regex characters such as '?'.

Comment: Why are you escaping all these characters?

Comment: 1. Because thats how I would do it, 2. It accounts for code variations, 3 it works.

Comment: `=` `"` `:` `<` `>` do not need to be escaped. The important ones are `.` and `?`.

Comment: `\s*=\s*"` 0 or more spaces